# mongodb lookup (aggregation)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have this function and I can't get it to work.

```
function GetDataTeacher(err){

Data_teacher.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "user": {
        "$toString": "$user"
      }
    }
  },
  {
     $lookup:
        {
           from: "Teacher",
           localField: "user",
           foreignField: "user",
           as: "info"
       }
  }
  ]).exec(function(err, results){
  console.log(results);
});
}
```

my models have in common

```
     user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
```

I don't understand what I can be doing wrong

Comment: Any specific error(or unexpected result) from the aggregate query?

Comment: My guess is you created the collections using mongoose and it changed `Teacher` collection into `Teachers` as mongoose is stupid. try changing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible issues here are:

1, You are converting the user id to string(which was already of type id)

`user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },`

so no need of converting to string and you can do this directly.

```
Data_teacher.aggregate([
  {
     $lookup:
        {
           from: "users",
           localField: "user",
           foreignField: "user",
           as: "info"
       }
  }
  ])
```

2, Please check if you have the user field in both the collections (`Data_teacher` and `Teacher`).

3, check if `localfield` and `foreignfield` are correct